# Does google pub sub deliver messages to dead letter queues with the same message id?

Tags: google-bigquery, dead-letter, messageid

If you have topic `t1` with subscriber `s1` and `s1` has dead letter forwarding to topic `t2` with subscription `s2`, then do messages delivered to `s1` have the same ids as their versions delivered to `s2`?

My preliminary testing indicates the ids are not the same but I'll need to double check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observation is correct only `messageid`s are unique per topic even for dead letters.
According to the [google cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/PubsubMessage)

> ID of the message, is assigned by the server when the message is published to be unique within the topic. Pub/sub guarantees that messageId is always unique per topic.